# Split and check in where condition in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `T_HISTORY` which can have multiple entries for an `item_ID` and `event_cd = 'route'` and `cmnt_txt`

I want to add a where condition in which `cmnt_txt` should have something after '-'

Currently I am running this query

```
SELECT 
    H.ITEM_ID, (U.FNAME_NM+ ' '+ U.LNAME_NM) AS USER_NM,
    H.EVENT_DT, H.CMNT_TXT
FROM 
    (SELECT 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY item_id ORDER BY EVENT_DT DESC) rn, *
     FROM 
         T_HISTORY
     WHERE 
         (EVENT_CD = 'comment' or EVENT_CD like 'ROUTE_INFO') 
         OR (EVENT_CD = 'ROUTE' AND CMNT_TXT != 'Item Routed'))H 
 LEFT JOIN 
     T_USER U on H.USER_NM = U.USER_NM
 WHERE 
     rn = 1;
```

which is returning this data:

```
ITEM_ID  USER_NM         EVENT_DT                 CMNT_TXT
142      GM 443          2016-04-20 13:10:10.503  Item Routed from jcruz - test
97       Austin Crocker  2016-04-20 11:25:27.580  Item Routed from rwwilson - 
139      Admin COR360    2016-04-25 08:53:58.563  Item Routed from mstrose - 
212      Admin COR360    2016-05-05 09:16:23.700  Item Routed from appr2 - 
303      Admin COR360    2016-08-18 07:19:05.630  Item Routed from jdavis - Test Watchdog notification
424      Admin COR360    2016-12-08 02:14:01.743  second comment
555      Admin COR360    2016-08-18 07:39:21.143  Item Routed from appr2 - Watchdog notification test
559      Admin COR360    2016-08-18 08:42:52.400  Item Routed from appr2 - New work arrived entry
71       Alston Moore    2016-05-13 11:52:52.963  Item Routed from bnunn - 
77       Alston Moore    2016-05-02 15:09:24.010  Delete from route for info
119      Alston Moore    2016-05-13 15:31:27.803  Item Routed from bnunn - 
128      Alston Moore    2016-04-28 11:05:57.533  Item Routed from bnunn - PLEASE APPROVE
140      Alston Moore    2016-04-27 17:39:24.047  Item Routed from bnunn - please approve, may need additional approval
217      Alston Moore    2016-05-13 11:51:59.630  Item Routed from bnunn - 
400      Approver 1      2016-12-09 07:46:52.650  A appr1 test comment... 
412      Approver 1      2016-12-09 08:23:26.180  Test Approver 1 Test Comment 001...
441      Approver 1      2016-12-14 03:58:45.280  Item Routed from admincor360 - testing comments
472      Approver 1      2016-11-21 04:37:42.970  Item Routed from admincor360 - 
552      Approver 1      2016-08-17 10:48:34.997  Item Routed from admincor360 - 
567      Approver 1      2016-11-21 04:39:03.580  Item Routed from admincor360 - 
15       Approver 2      2016-11-21 01:19:00.740  Item Routed from appr1 - 
30       Approver 2      2016-04-22 16:59:06.153  Item Routed from admincor360
388      Approver 2      2016-08-17 10:14:52.823  Item Routed from admincor360 - 
434      Approver 2      2016-08-17 10:16:21.670  Item Routed from admincor360 - 
438      Approver 2      2016-08-19 05:46:36.047  Item Routed from admincor360 - test time interval task email body 10000437
553      Approver 2      2016-08-18 08:10:27.133  Item Routed from admincor360 - New work entry for approver 2
566      Approver 2      2016-08-19 07:11:43.883  Item Routed from admincor360 - test SSO
```

link CRM

And didnt want the first part

Comment: From your accepted answer I gather that you only want CMNT_TXT that contain a dash. That is not clear from your description. It would have been way better to simply show the rows you do want in your results rather than adding "And didnt want the first part".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to want:

```
where cmnt_text like '%-_%'
```

The `_` guarantees that there is at least one character.

If you want a non-space character after the hyphen:

```
where cmnt_text like '%-%[^ ]%'
```

Answer (score 3):

`WHERE rn = 1 and right(rtrim(H.CMNT_TXT),1)<>'-'`